# How can I auto remove the white space?

Tags: html, css, removing-whitespace

I am processing various RSS news items.

In those items, some of them always have various white spaces (like tabs, redundant space, etc) in front within `<p></p>` or `<div></div>`.

How can I automatically remove those unnecessary white spaces in the beginning of a paragraph, using pure HTML or CSS?

Comment: @Baszz as far as I can see, the two questions are unrelated.

Comment: What happened? someone thought two questions are related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible. HTML nor CSS are not programming languages, as such, they do not contain the tools to preform string manipulation.

You could do it easily with javascript like so:

```
var str = "This is a      string with           multiple spaces";
str = str.replace(/ {2,}/g, " ");
document.write("<pre>" + str + "</pre>");
```

Will print

```
This is a string with multiple spaces
```

**[Consider this working example](http://jsfiddle.net/uqJyG/)**

Comment: Thanks! I don't know anything about js. if the html string is like <p>     this is a       string with      many spaces" </p>, how can I use js to retrieve the text inside the <p></p> and do the processing?

Comment: In that case you could just parse it with the `<p>`, or you could select it if it has an ID or a class. May I suggest the excellent JavaScript tutorial on MDN? [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/javascript)

Answer (score 1):

you can use CSS for doing this:

```
div
{
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

or

```
p
{
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will never wrap to the next line. The text continues on the same line until a 
 tag is encountered

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If using jQuery, there's the [`jQuery.trim()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)

JavaScript doesn't provide a trim function but [here's an example](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-trim.html) how to write it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot process HTML element with HTML or CSS.
You need a JS for this.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue
I solved it using "white space attribute"

**example :**

```
p{
    white-space: normal;
}
```